# What is the difference between the CAs available for upgrade in AWS RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a PostgreSQL RDS instance that currently uses the SSL/TLS certificate `rds-ca-2019`. It's recommended to update to a new CA.

The options are `rds-ca-ecc384-g1`, `rds-ca-rsa4096-g1`, or `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`.

What is the difference between the CAs?

Answer (score 8):

TLDR: for a drop-in replacement, use `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`

---

`rds-ca-2019` certificates are set to expire in August, 2024.

The new CA certificates are:

- `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1` (RSA 2048)
- `rds-ca-rsa4096-g1` (RSA 4096)
- `rds-ca-ecc384-g1` (ECC 384)

A good general guideline, as [recommended by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.RegionCertificateAuthorities), is to use `rds-ca-rsa2048-g1`, which offers the same security as `rds-ca-2019`. The main difference between the CAs is the private key algorithm and lesser so, the signing algorithm.

The available CAs will depend on the DB engine and DB engine version. If you need stronger security, you can also use `rds-ca-rsa4096-g1` or `rds-ca-ecc384-g1` as they use stronger algorithms. However, keep in mind that not all clients or systems may support the more complex RSA 4096 or ECC 384 algorithms.